# scp command working in bash doesn't work in zsh

Tags: zsh, scp

This command works fine in bash:

```
bash-3.2$ scp luna4:/u/paige/maye/src/diviner/notebooks/plots/hk_* .
hk_az.png                                                   100%  126KB 126.0KB/s   00:00
hk_baffle.png                                               100%  166KB 166.3KB/s   00:01
hk_bb.png                                                   100%  144KB 143.8KB/s   00:00
hk_el.png                                                   100%  115KB 115.3KB/s   00:00
hk_fpa.png                                                  100%  123KB 123.2KB/s   00:00
hk_fpb.png                                                  100%  126KB 125.7KB/s   00:00
hk_hybrid.png                                               100%   99KB  98.7KB/s   00:00
hk_oba.png                                                  100%  140KB 139.7KB/s   00:00
hk_solar.png                                                100%  206KB 205.6KB/s   00:00
hk_temp.png                                                 100%   62KB  61.8KB/s   00:00
hk_yoke.png                                                 100%  122KB 121.7KB/s   00:00
bash-3.2$ exit
```

but in zsh it fails, no files are found:

```
$ scp luna4:/u/paige/maye/src/diviner/notebooks/plots/hk_* .
zsh: no matches found: luna4:/u/paige/maye/src/diviner/notebooks/plots/hk_*
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that `zsh` is [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) the remote path. You can verify this by

```
scp luna4:"/u/paige/maye/src/diviner/notebooks/plots/hk_*" .
```

To turn globbing off for scp remote paths, but otherwise leave globbing the same (from [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00495.html)) add this to your `.zshrc` -

```
# Disable globbing on the remote path.
alias scp='noglob scp_wrap'
function scp_wrap {
  local -a args
  local i
  for i in "$@"; do case $i in
    (*:*) args+=($i) ;;
    (*) args+=(${~i}) ;;
  esac; done
  command scp "${(@)args}"
}
```

Answer (score 19):

If you use single quotes, then it works:

```
scp 'remote.host.com:files*' .
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me the frustration having just switch from bash.

Comment: My preferred answer. Thank you.